# HttpServlet class not able to find mysql jar when hibernate called first while the same works in a different order of execution

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I know there are similar questions in forum, **BUT THIS IS A WEIRD AND DIFF SCENARIO**,

I am loading a Java web App with a servlet call first (say InitServlet).

In that InitServlet when I make an external function call which in turn will make Database calls using hibernate, it fails with

````
```org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection```
````

*It fails at buildSessionFactory*

**But in the same servlet, I added a block of code which makes a jdbc call as first logic and then calling above mentioned a hibernate function works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

Now by adding `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before hibernate call also works fine. Is it the only way to make this work.

Why can't the application load the related jar, when it is available under tomcat/lib folder. Below is the `hibernate.cfg` snippet for your reference

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver.class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
```

Comment: It should work. If you want to understand what is so special about your case, debug into `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl#buildPool` to see what is happening and why Hibernate can't load the driver.

Answer (score 0):

first put the database xml file in your project source folder,and put the all jars in your project library.** Below is the (hibernate.cfg) snippet for your reference**

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdetails
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```